# NavigatorIOS titleTextColor for leftButtonTitle

Tags: react-native

I am trying to use the NavigatorIOS component for navigation in my app. In my designer comp it has some text along the left, which it appears I can use leftButtonTitle to achieve. However they also have the text black. It looks like when I set the titleTextColor prop on my NavigatorIOS component, it only applies to the central title and not the leftButtonTitle. Is there any way I can make the leftButtonTitle text black?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like setting the tintColor will affect the leftButtonTitle.